# How do I get an IVsDebugger object in the NuGet Package Manager Console?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, automation, nuget

How do I get an `IVsDebugger` object in the `NuGet Package Manager Console` ? I want to automate remote-debugging operations.

I miss those macros so much! :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
Debugger debugger = _applicationObject.Debugger;

DTE dte = debugger.DTE;

ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider((IServiceProvider)dte);

IVsDebugger dbg = (IVsDebugger)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger));
```

Comment: Well, this is `C#`, not `PowerShell`, but I'll convert it to `PowerShell` and try it. Thanks